# python find seperate string from mixed string and providing space

Tags: python

Consider i have a `list:[my, python, dynamic`]

and i am getting a raw_input as string from user,

eg:
`if raw_input is 'mypython' as single string`,then i need to provide space between the string,since they are seperate words in list:
so it need to print as `my python`
Please help,i searched for the answer but not getting want i really need.

```
list=['my','python','dynamic']
s1 = raw_input("enter string: ")
if s1 in list:
  print s1 + #<-stuck in here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over the wrong thing:

```
list=['my','python','dynamic']
s1 = raw_input("enter string: ")
print ' '.join([i for i in list if i in s1])
```

Prints: `my python`

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to simply ask the user to correct themselves

```
l=['my','python','dynamic']

valid_input = False

while not valid_input:
  s1 = raw_input("enter string: ")
  s2 = s1.split(' ')  # break up string into "words"
  valid_input = True
  for word in s2:
    if word not in l:
      print "invalid input"
      valid_input = False
      break
```

This assumes the user can input an empty string as well.